# save outputs at a different location R

Tags: r, directory

I am looping through all the files in a directory and creating some reports and jpeg files. I would like to save these reports and pictures and a sub folder instead.

Is there a better way to do this without 
setwd() back and forth in the loop?

for example:

```
for (j in 1:length(list.files()))
{
 sp=read.csv(list.files()[j])
#do something
  setwd("H:\test\sub")
  jpeg(paste(list.files()[j],'.jpg',sep=""))
  hist(data)
  dev.off() 
  setwd("H:\test")
#do more 
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Better how? You have to specify the specific destination path somehow. Currently you're switching the working dir. The alternative would be to simply paste together the full path.

Comment: This is cumbersome moving back and forth. Definitely slows down the process. As a perl, unix user it is usually straight to specify output dir.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, just set the *destiny path* that you want to save:

```
jpeg(your_path_here, ...)
```

Like this

```
files = list.files()

for(file in files){
  dir = paste("H:\\test\\sub\\", file, ".jpg", sep = "")
  jpeg(dir)
  hist(data)
  dev.off()
}
```